# New to Ubuntu -- loaded my weather..now what

Tags: weather, my-weather-indicator

Loaded my weather indicator for 16.04, did the sudo steps and it completed without error. How do I start it running? It is not on the list of programs on the left of the screen and there is no icon for it. I am sure it is in the machine but it is not obvious to me where.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Super key or click in the launcher Ubuntu icon, then write the name of the program (you can try typing"indicator"in this case) and just hit enter.

Easy peasy.